# Nu Html Checker Error "A numeric character reference expanded to carriage return." when using "&#013;"

Tags: html, w3c-validation, carriage-return

I want to use a carriage return in attribute title.
And I have this HTML code:

```
<a href="javascript:;" title="Line 1 &#013;Line 2">Link Text</a>
```

But [Nu Html](https://validator.w3.org/) Checker throws the error:

> 【Error】 A numeric character reference expanded to carriage return.

Also tried to use `&#xD;`, but got the same error.

I want to resolve this error, what can I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`&#013;` and `&#xD;` are numeric character references which escape the Unicode control character "CARRIAGE RETURN" (per [UnicodeData.txt](ftp://ftp.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt)).

In HTML, text (as in [attribute values](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-html52-20171214/syntax.html#elements-attributes)) [must not](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-html52-20171214/syntax.html#character-references) contain control characters (other than space characters):

> The numeric character reference forms described above are allowed to reference any Unicode code point other than […] [control characters](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-html52-20171214/infrastructure.html#control-characters) other than [space characters](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-html52-20171214/infrastructure.html#space-characters).

According to the linked definition, "CARRIAGE RETURN" isn’t a space character.

If you want a line break, you can use `&#10;`/`&#xA;`, which escape the Unicode control character "LINE FEED", but this one is defined to be a space character, so it’s allowed in text.

```html
<a href="javascript:;" title="Line 1&#10;Line 2">Link Text</a>
```

```html
<a href="javascript:;" title="Line 1&#xA;Line 2">Link Text</a>
```

From the definition of the [`title` attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-html52-20171214/dom.html#the-title-attribute):

> If the `title` attribute’s value contains U+000A LINE FEED (LF) characters, the content is split into multiple lines. Each U+000A LINE FEED (LF) character represents a line break.

Note that you could also add a line break like this:

```html
<a href="javascript:;" title="Line 1
Line 2">Link Text</a>
```

Comment: The first solution with &#10; is HTML invalid but the 2nd solution with &#xA; is HTML valid. (Message for the first solution: "Error: A numeric character reference expanded to carriage return.") - The last solution with 'line break' is not really nice ;-)

Comment: @AxelS: Which validator do you use? The `&#10;` variant validates with https://validator.w3.org/nu/ – I’m surprised by the message you quote, because the character is LINE FEED, not CARRIAGE RETURN.

Comment: I used validator.w3.org/nu and it gave me an error message but with &#xA; it's valid... I don't know why it gave an error message with the first solution...